# Getting script errors when generating SQL script for Azure using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am using the free azure websites and made an sql database. I need to create the db tables, and then insert the dummy in.

I tried to generate the scripts through sql management studio but I get a lot of errors when I run it against the azure db.

```
Msg 40508, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'CONTAINMENT'.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL'.
```

How can I get the data into my azure database?

Comment: By fixing the errors?  SQL Server Management Studio just auto-generates SQL statements behind the scenes, and is apparently not Azure-aware, so you'll have to write the SQL by hand yourself, or modify the scripts it creates to eliminate the errors.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - SQL Server Management Studio supports SQL Database-compatible output.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Yes, but not Azure-friendly SQL Database compatible output.  Read the wording of the error messages.

Comment: "SQL Database" = "SQL Azure" (it was renamed about a year ago). I suspect the OP generated creation scripts without choosing the right option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42446/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-david-makogon)

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a guess here, based on the errors: When generating scripts via SSMS, you need to specify output specific to Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure). I don't have it installed at the moment so I can't provide you with a screenshot. I'll update my answer, should I get it installed before you verify this is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

as David mentioned above, you can specify the script generation to target Windows Azure SQL Database

[image]

Comment: Still not working when I try to generate the data(the insert statements).I get "Msg 40054, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again." Is there some other option I need? I don't know why make it so difficult to insert data into the database.

Comment: the error says it all, you can have tables without clustered index in Azure SQL Database. i suggest you use the Migration Wizard to move  your DB to Azure (http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) so you can analyse it for incompatibilities as well.

Comment: So what does the "Sql Azure Database" option actually do I would have thought it would make all tables and data compliant with Azure Database.

Comment: generate script will not add stuff that's not in your database. if you don't have a clustered index, it wont create one for you.

Edit: The comment above should read: "the error says it all, you CAN'T have tables without clustered index in Azure SQL Database"

Comment: Ok I am now using that tool but not sure how to use those bcd(.dat) files it generates.

Comment: The setting is located under Tools -> Options -> Sql Server Object Explorer -> Scripting

Answer (score 1):

Hi this may be a little late but I found the [this link](http://www.sqlideas.com/2015/10/use-statement-is-not-supported-to.html) to be helpful:

You basically have to manualy change the context (click on the correct database on the list of dropdown)  before executing the query. You may have noticed this when working between databases.

Hope this helps